# ejabberd: ldap_filter in LDAP Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, groups, ejabberd

**TL;DR: How to setup ejabberd to only allow some Active Directory group members?**

Hello,

After having successfully set up an ejabberd service plugged in to our AD, I'd like to narrow the allowed users to a specific group.

My working setup is :

```
auth_method: [ldap]
ldap_servers:
  - 1.2.3.4
  - 1.2.3.5
ldap_uids:
  mail: "%u@domain.lan"
ldap_base: "OU=FON,OU=Domain,OU=Global,DC=domain,DC=lan"
ldap_rootdn: "CN=someone,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=lan"
ldap_password: "secret"
```

This is working fine as is.

---

The users are stored in :

`"OU=Utilisateurs,OU=FON,OU=Domain,OU=Global,DC=domain,DC=lan"`

but the groups are stored in another OU :

`"OU=Securite,OU=Groupes,OU=FON,OU=Domain,OU=Global,DC=domain,DC=lan"`

I'd like to add a filter to allow only users contained in a group which is defined in another OU.

When trying to add the filter below, ***zero*** user in the allowed group can connect :

```
ldap_filter:
  (&(objectCategory=group)(CN=GG_XMPP_USERS,OU=Securite,OU=Groupes,OU=FON,OU=Domain,OU=Global,DC=domain,DC=lan))
```

To no avail, I also tried some syntax looking like :
`(&(objectclass=group)(|(cn=admingroup)(cn=group1)(cn=group2)))`

In Active Directory, the user objects have no "memberOf" attribute one could query.

So what is the correct way to go?

Comment: (&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=GG_XMPP_USERS,OU=Securite,OU=Groupes,OU=FON,OU=Domain,OU=Global,DC=domain,DC=lan))
I guess

Comment: Thank you @Manu, this was the correct way to go. You're great.